# Difference between two sql count and subquery count statements

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Is there a big performance difference between those two sql count statements, when performing large counts (large here means 100k + records)

first:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE <some very complex conditions>
```

second:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE <some very complex conditions>) subquery_alias
```

I know that first approach is right, but i want to know is this statements will perform similar ?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see how the database will execute your queries. In this case there is no difference at all, the same queryplan for both queries. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query optimizer will most likely transform your second query into the first one. There should be no measurable performance difference between those two queries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on Database being used. for MS SQL the Query Optimizer will optimize the query and both will have similar performance. But for other database system it depends on the intelligence of the Query Optimizer.

Comment: PostgreSQL does the same, executes both queries the same.